# Multiple variable assignment vs HashTable lookup

Tags: c#, optimization

I'm writing a CUIT ( Coded UI Test ) and I'm replacing variables with data fetched from a csv.

Example:

```
this.UIMap.IDBParams.UITboxFsEditText = TestContext.DataRow["num_fs"].ToString();
this.UIMap.IDBParams.UIArmGlCheckBoxChecked = Convert.ToBoolean(TestContext.DataRow["arm_gl"]);
```

But I'm having to **define over 100 variables**.

My concept of how I would implement a hash table here is :

- On start-up fetch all the variables on each test method and make a new HashMap with the variables as key. Ex:

  ```
  {
   this.UIMap.IDBParams.UITboxFsEditText :  ,
   this.UIMap.IDBParams.UIArmGlCheckBoxChecked : ,
  } //indented just for visual clarity
  ```
- Fetch the csv columns and assign them as value for each key. Ex:

  ```
  {
   this.UIMap.IDBParams.UITboxFsEditText : 
      TestContext.DataRow["num_fs"].ToString() ,
   this.UIMap.IDBParams.UIArmGlCheckBoxChecked : 
      Convert.ToBoolean(TestContext.DataRow["arm_gl"]) ,
  } //indented just for visual clarity
  ```

Is this the best approach ?

Does reading a HashTable index ( ex: `MyTable['UiTboxFsEditText']` ) acts the same as the line `this.UIMap.IDBParams.UITboxFsEditText = TestContext.DataRow["num_fs"].ToString();` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "best?"  You're on the right track; just go for it.

Comment: By best I mean both efficient and clean.. My screen looks all filled with assignments, and I'm not very experienced with this so I might be talking nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me you're doing the same amount of work either way. In one place you're filling a HashMap, and the other you're doing variable assignment. Maybe one is fewer lines of code? Almost certainly the version using the HashMap will be somewhat more complicated (due to the indirection) than the version using simple assignment. There will be almost no difference in runtime performance.

You have to ask yourself if it's really worth spending the effort to design the HashMap version when there's little to gain. Especially in test code, which you should strive to make simple.